# How to use method for pan gestures in swift 3?

Tags: ios

This line is giving me error:

> let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handlePan")))

Comment: let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan)). Use this line.

Comment: I've tried it but still its not working.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Would have been nice if you provided the error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understood your problem it will be solved by changing in syntax a little bit. I also faced this once. Try this

```
let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomTableViewCell.handlePanTest(_:)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @AXY